# $|x-x_{0}||x+x_{0}| \leq 2|x-x_{0}|(|a|+|b|)$ if $x,x_{0} \in [a,b]$

Tags: inequality

How does one obtain the above bound for the product $|x-x_{0}||x+x_{0}|$, if $x$ and $x_{0}$ are assumed to be points in the closed interval $[a,b]$?

I can easily see that $|x-x_{0}||x+x_{0}| \leq 2|x-x_{0}||b|$, from $|x+x_{0}| \leq |x|+|x_{0}| \leq 2|b|$. But I couldn't obtain the bound involving $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not necessarily true that $|x|,|x_0|\le|b|$: consider the case $a=-1$ and $b=0$.

The result is clear if $x=x_0$. If $x\ne x_0$, divide through by $|x-x_0|$ to get the equivalent inequality

$$|x+x_0|\le 2(|a|+|b|)\;.$$

Now $|y|\le\max\{|a|,|b|\}$ for each $y\in[a,b]$, so

$$\begin{align*}
|x+x_0|&\le|x|+|x_0|\\
&\le2\max\{|a|,|b|\}\\
&\le 2(|a|+|b|)\;,
\end{align*}$$

since $\max\{|a|,|b|\}\le|a|+|b|$.

Comment: So the key is $|y|\le\max\{|a|,|b|\}$, which I'm guessing is the first thing one encounters in basic real analysis, but of which I'm not aware =( . This is in Courant's Calculus book, where the final inequality was presented without any explanation.

Comment: @Maxis: It’s been a long time since I saw it, but my recollection is that Courant’s book leaves quite a bit of detail to the reader; in particular, I’m not surprised that the reader is expected to work out both that inequality and the fact that $\max\{|a|,|b|\}\le|a|+|b|$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x \in [-2,-1]$ (here is $b=-1$), then

$|x| \le |b|=1$

is correct only for $x=-1$! Thus, your conclusion

$ |x|+|x_0| \le 2|b|$

is wrong, in general.

Now, try to prove that if $x \in [a,b]$, then it holds that

$|x| \le |a|+|b|$.